# Has ArcMap's background progress bar been fixed in 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-10.2

I don't know if any other geoprocessing tool authors are pondering whether to invest the time and effort in a workaround for this "feature", but

- in 10.0 background processing tasks had a progress bar indication both at the bottom of the main window and as a little 'clock' in the results window
- in 10.1 the progress indication is gone, for background processes

Has anyone installed 10.2 yet?  Have we got it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "have we got it back".
But the behavior is the same for 10.1 and 10.2. Anything executing in the background has a status bar in the bottom right of the application with a message indicating something is executing. If you click that bar, it'll open up the Results window to that executing tool where you can read the messages.

If you're referring to the point that sometimes the bar doesnt appear when you launch a tool: Yes, this is something I've heard of, but this behavior hasn't been "fixed". We've investigated it, but can't pin down why it happens for some people and not others. If you start background processing from Geoprocessing menu > Options > Enabled BG > OK - the bar should be at the bottom. I've never once seen/heard of that method not displaying the bar at the bottom.

So in short, we changed the message style in the bottom right bar between 10 and 10.1. But 10.1 and 10.2 have the same behavior.

Note: I work at Esri on the Geoprocessing Team.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the useful reply.  In 10.1, I see a status bar in the bottom right of the ArcMap window appear for each background tool, telling me which tool is running, but that bar doesn't tell me the % complete.  Nor does the results window.  In 10.0 on the other hand the status bar would display a percentage, and the tool's executing icon would appear as a little clock dial showing progress - both these features are gone in 10.1. Is there a way to re-enable them?  I am using 64 bit b/g processing btw.

Comment: When I do a merge, I get no status bar... no indication at all what the status of the process is.  The only thing I can do is go to the folder where the output file is being created and look to see if the file size is still changing.  This is very inconvenient.  I am using 10.1 with remote connection.